# Running SonarQube From Eclipse Receiving 500 Error - Out Of Memory Error on SonarQube Server

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I am using the SonarQube Eclipse plug-in to scan source-code locally and ran into a 500 error. This of course caused the scan to fail. Please see the scan log file below:

```
Retrieve remote issues of project myProject...
Start SonarQube analysis on myProject...
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.1
14:24:12.508 INFO  - Load global referentials...
14:24:12.703 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 196 ms
14:24:12.703 INFO  - Incremental mode
14:24:12.715 INFO  - User cache: /home/name/.sonar/cache
14:24:12.725 INFO  - Install plugins
14:24:12.739 INFO  - Include plugins: 
14:24:12.740 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, buildbreaker, scmactivity, views, jira
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://server-name:9000/batch_bootstrap/db?project=myproject_vobs_project]. Response code: 500
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:281)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:235)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:116)
    at com.google.common.io.Files.copy(Files.java:231)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.download(ServerClient.java:70)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.downloadDatabase(PreviewDatabase.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.start(PreviewDatabase.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:81)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 6 more
```

Does anyone know what I am missing? Why does the scan fail? I am completely confused. The SonarQube server is up and running on the local Intranet and scanning from Eclipse has worked on previous SonarQube projects. Although, these previous projects were smaller (less code).

**UPDATE**

I just checked SonarQube's logs and it looks like scanning remotely from Eclipse is causing an out of memory error on the SonarQube machine. 0_o

Here is a paste of the log: `2015.08.27 10:27:42 ERROR web[rails]
Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError (Java heap space):`

**FURTHER UPDATE**

I found a bug report that mentions the Eclipse plug-in that seems like a similar but also different issue. Maybe, there is a possibility,this could help troubleshoot the 500 error. Please find the URL here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5511

[image: Fiat 500 Error]

Regards,

Comment: Please have a look at server side logs. HTTP 500 means there is a server side error.

Comment: Thank-you for the helpful comment. I will check this. What is the folder on the server with the logs, just in case I cannot find them myself?

Comment: <sonarqube install dir>/logs :)